# CMake all_object_files target

Tags: cmake

I want to create a CMake target to build all object files.
To do this, I first modified all targets to build an object file lib and link against it:

```
add_library(exe_object_files OBJECT ${sources})
add_executable(exe $<TARGET_OBJECTS:exe_object_files>)
```

Since I have multiple executables, I added a target for all object files and added the targets for each executable as dependency:

```
add_custom_target(all_exe_object_files)
add_dependencies(all_exe_object_files exe_object_files)
```

This adds a `all_exe_object_files` target I can make, but making the target does nothing.

Then I tried adding the object files as sources:

```
get_target_property(all_exe_object_files_sources all_exe_object_files SOURCES)
if(NOT all_exe_object_files_sources)
    set(all_exe_object_files_sources)
endif()
list(APPEND all_exe_object_files_sources $<TARGET_OBJECTS:exe_object_files>)
set_target_properties(all_exe_object_files PROPERTIES SOURCES "${all_exe_object_files_sources}")
```

This did not help.

I guess the reason is that `add_library(... OBJECT ...)` behaves similar to `add_custom_command` and the files are only build if a target uses them (and my custom target probably does not count as using the generated files).

What am I doing wrong and how can I create a target to build all object files?